# Corrupted members in Rcpp Module

Tags: rcpp

I have a class and a vector of pointers to instances of the class in c++. I want to be able to query both kinds of objects in R using Rcpp. However the data member of my class seems to get corrupted for no reason. Since I'm not able to consistently reproduce the error I'm guessing it has something to do with memory being released that shouldn't have.

I have also tried designing my own container class, but it suffered from the same problem.

Below I have tried to make a minimal example

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class Element{
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    Element() : x(0){};
    Element(int x_) : x(x_){};
    void display() {Rcpp::Rcout << x << std::endl;}
};

typedef std::vector<Element*> Container;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Element)

//R Side

RCPP_MODULE(mod){
  class_<Element>("Element")
    .constructor<int>()
    .method("display", & Element::display);


  class_<Container>("Container")
    .constructor()
    .constructor<int>()
    .method("push_back", & Container::push_back)
    .const_method("at", & Container::at )
    .const_method("size", & Container::size )
  ;
}

/*** R
container <- new(Container)

container$push_back( new(Element, 5))
container$push_back( new(Element, 6))

container$size()

myElements <- list()
myElements[[1]] <- container$at(0)
myElements[[1]]$display()
*/
```

I had to query a few more times in R to get the error below is my output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/Element.cpp')
> container <- new(Container)
> container$push_back( new(Element, 5))
> container$push_back( new(Element, 6))
> container$size()
[1] 2
> myElements <- list()
> myElements[[1]] <- container$at(0)
> myElements[[1]]$display()
5
> myElements[[2]] <- container$at(1)
> myElements[[1]]$display()
5
> myElements[[2]]$display()
6
> myElements[[1]]$display()
61412608
```

EDIT: 
I was able to compile this in a windows environment after adding two functions

```
Element* container_at(std::vector<Element*> * vec, int i){
  return vec->at(i);
}

int container_size(std::vector<Element*> * vec){
  return vec->size();
}
```

and replacing

```
.const_method("at", & Container::at )
.const_method("size", & Container::size )
```

with

```
.method("at", & container_at )
.method("size", & container_size )
```

Comment: I get several screens full of warnings when I compile your code (on Windows).  On Linux, it just fails.  "Minimal reproducible examples", please.

Comment: @Dirk I have just copied the above code into a new .cpp file. And I was fully able to run it in R from terminal. I'm running on Linux.

Comment: Which Rcpp version, which R version, which G++ version, ... ? It failed for me on Ubuntu 13.04, everything current as released.

Comment: Hi Dirk, Tobias -- I can compile the code successfully on Mac OSX Mavericks w/ `clang`, latest CRAN Rcpp. I got a segfault after running the R code supplied a few times. I can investigate a bit.

Comment: R 3.0.1, Rcpp 0.10.6, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1

Comment: If I run `library(Rcpp); gctorture(TRUE); sourceCpp("Element.cpp")` I get the error `Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘size’, should be from class “integer” or a subclass (was class “character”)`.

Comment: @Tobias: I have the same setup, and it didn't even build: neither with clang nor with g++-4.7.

Comment: @Dirk That is weird. I have just tried to compile the code in a windows environment and after introducing the few changes mentioned in the edit above it did. Furthermore the class member still gets overwritten.

Comment: @Tobias: Sorry, I may have had an unreleased Rcpp version install (we were in  the middle of chasing a bug). With the released version, and the code as above, as I can now replicate.  It is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug. Can you log it here: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues?state=open

I have a good idea of what it might be and how it can be fixed, but I might not have time for a few days.